# Как получить массив из всех пунктов тега Select? React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Подскажите как получить массив из всех value select'a

Пример select:

```
 <select name="" id="sel">

   <option value="" hidden="">Выбрать из готовых</option>
   <option value="Подождите немного" hidden="">подождите</option>
   <option value="Оператор X на связи" hidden="">оператор</option>

    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Так как у тебя написан id=sel, то можно рассчитывать на то, что DOM не будет меняться и использовать querySelector

```js
document.querySelectorAll("#sel option").forEach(element => {
  console.log(element.getAttribute("value"))
})
```

Если нужно именно в React, то используй ref и сделай тот же самый forEach но на children ref'а